# Laravel DB::listen get controller & method from which the query was called

Tags: php, laravel

As suggested in https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database

I have

```
DB::listen(function(query) {
  ....
});
```

to log a query from my Laravel application.

I'd also like to find out which controller or function that this query was called from. How could I achieve that? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the query is being fired during a request you should be able to use this.

```
DB::listen(function($query) {
     dd($this->app->request->route()->action['uses']);
});

output:  "App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@someAction"
```

There is also `$this->app->request->route()->action['controller']`

There may be ways to use `$this-app` to reach the controller in none request situations.